# Remove AUTO_INCREMENT from a table? (not from a particular row)

Tags: mysql, sql

Making an sql database

```
U_MAIL
U_PNUMBER
U_ID (PK)
U_ADDRESS
U_PASSWORD
```

Accidentally whilst doing this i managed to set the whole table to auto increment rather than just the field `U_ID`. Is there any way of deleting this so i can then set `U_ID` to auto increment? I have googled but can't find anything related to deleting it from table, just from  a particular field

Comment: What does _set the whole table to auto increment_ mean? Can you post your `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything which creates whole table with auto_increments except human mistake, but if this is the problem and data doesn't matter you can DROP and recreate table having only U_ID with auto increment.

but if want to remove all auto increment except U_ID, you have fire alter table command for each cloumn, like:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE U_MAIL      U_MAIL     <datat_type>;
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE U_PNUMBER   U_PNUMBER  <datat_type>;
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE U_ADDRESS   U_ADDRESS  <datat_type>;
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE U_PASSWORD  U_PASSWORD <datat_type>;
```

By this Commands we are redefining each column with clean data_type(without auto_increment).
so it will solve your problem.

For more ALTER TABLE information Click: [**MySQL Alter Table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: yeah it was completely human error, data doesnt matter too much so will just drop and redo, was hoping there was a quicker way but thanks anyway